# Spring Security SAML - principle attributes not showing

Tags: spring, saml, userid

I have deployed SAML sample application. I have also registered with SSOCircle and am able to login correctly.

On the authenticated page - Principal's SAML attributes are showing nothing. Here I was expecting first name, last name etc.

Also for every thing like name, principle , name id - all are showing my email address, where I was expecting one of them to be my user id.

```
Name:   om.singh@XXXX.com
Principal:  om.sXX@XXXX.com
Name ID:    om.sXX@XXXX.com
```

Any suggesting as I need to get the first name, last name and also the user id.

Regards
Om

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code :

```
    public Object loadUserBySAML(SAMLCredential credential) throws UsernameNotFoundException 
    {
        String userName = credential.getNameID().getValue();
        String email     = credential.getAttributeAsString("EmailAddress");
        String firstName = credential.getAttributeAsString("FirstName");
        String lastName  = credential.getAttributeAsString("LastName");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check which attributes are being returned in the authentication assertion, in the implementation of your SAMLUserDetailsService you could do something like:

```
@Override
public Object loadUserBySAML(SAMLCredential samlCredential) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    String userID = samlCredential.getNameID().getValue();
    for(Attribute attr : samlCredential.getAttributes()) {
        String[] attrVals = samlCredential.getAttributeAsStringArray(attr.getName());
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(attrVals));
        LOG.info(String.format("%s (%s) : %s", attr.getName(), attr.getFriendlyName(), values));
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

ok, may not be the best way to extract the details but you get the idea.